# Word for expressing ongoing problems

Tags: single-word-requests

How to express the continuity of certain problems shown earlier with statistics? Meaning that these problems did not disappear during the observed period.

> Despite positive temporal trends, the problems remained **detectable** until the end of the study period.

> Despite positive temporal trends, the problems remained **apparent** until the end of the study period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a good option is to use a verb that captures the concept concisely, such a verb as "perdure" for instance.

- Despite positive temporal trends, the problems perdured/persisted until the end of the study period.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/perdure) (intransitive) To continue to exist, last or endure, especially for a great length of time.

*perdure* is rarely used but its meaning fits your specification.

Comment: *Perdure* occurs on google ngram with a frequency 0.00000001 %, less than one ten thousandth that of *persist*, 0.0005 %. Perdure is not a good choice.

Comment: @Anton It is not often found, true, but "persist", "endure", "last" do not have the same connotations. Why reject a word because it is rare? Perhaps the particular connotations in "perdure" could appeal to some user of the language. After all, I merely consider a verb *such* as "perdure".

Answer (score 2):

Despite positive temporal trends, the problems endured until the end of the study period.

Comment: Continued is another option.